# Automate a Ruby command without it exiting

Tags: ruby

This hopefully should be an easy question to answer.  I am attempting to have mumble-ruby run automatically I have everything up and running except after running this simple script it runs but ends. In short:

- Running this from terminal I get "Press enter to terminate script" and it works.
- Running this via a cronjob runs the script but ends it and runs `cli.disconnect` (I assume).

I want the below script to run automatically via a cronjob at a specified time and not end until the server shuts down.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mumble-ruby'

cli = Mumble::Client.new('IP Address', Port, 'MusicBot', 'Password')
cli.connect
sleep(1)
cli.join_channel(5)
stream = cli.stream_raw_audio('/tmp/mumble.fifo')
stream.volume = 2.7

print 'Press enter to terminate script';
gets
cli.disconnect
```

Comment: If you don't want it to end, why do you want it to be a cron job? If it's something you want to kick off and not end until server reset, then use `nohup`. If you want it to automatically restart when the server reboots, you can put it in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`

Comment: Thanks for the response mbratch, as I said down below I am not an expert by any means and I am learning scripts and linux as I go.  If you could clarify why putting it in that would make it not end I would appreciate it.  I need this script to run after my server is up and running and mpd is all set up as well so that is why I chose a cronjob (it works, its just exiting mumble-ruby after execution). As a side note I have/etc/rc0.d through rc6.d not just rc.d does that matter?  Could you also show me where to put the code in rc.local if thats possible, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to skin this cat... :)

My thought was to take your script (call it `foo`) and remove the last 3 lines. In your `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file (NOTE: this applies to Ubuntu and Fedora, not sure what you're running - but it has something similar) you'd add `nohup /path_to_foo/foo 2>&1 > /dev/null&` to the end of the file so that it runs in the background. You can also run that command right at a terminal if you just want to run it and have it running. You have to make sure that `foo` is made executable with `chmod +x /path_to_foo/foo`.

Comment: can I add a sleep command or something similar so that it doesn't start up right away when I turn on and off my server? Reason being is I have another script that needs to wait until the server is completely up and running in order for this one to work.  Also as I said before in my /etc folder I have rc0.d through rc6.d and I also have /etc/rc.local which should I put it in? I dont have /etc/rc.d/rc.local is what I am trying to say :)

Comment: Sure, you could put a sleep at the beginning of the `foo` script. That way, your server boot isn't impacted but the action of `foo` will be delayed by the length of the sleep. You want to put it at the end of `/etc/rc.local`. Your system may be organized slightly different than mine (mine's Fedora).

Comment: nohup /usr/local/bin/Mumble.rb 2>&1 > /dev/null& is what I came up with I tried a restart and nothing but if I run as ./rc.local it proceeds through the scripts but when it gets to the end it still doesn't work properly.  Is their anything I can post that will give you more info?

Comment: Ignoring `rc.local` for the moment, when you run the nohup command manually with your script, does it run?

Comment: It does although I actually added a sleep 50000 to the end of my ruby script and if I navigate to /etc and run ./rc.local it runs the script and works I have everything set up right now I will let my server restart tonight and take it from their.  I will post again tomorrow with what I find.

Comment: OK great. If it doesn't run automatically on reboot, that means your system might need to be configured to use `rc.local`. I know on Fedora it has to be enabled through a system control command. On Ubuntu I'm not certain. You could Google `Ubuntu rc.local` and probably find an answer to that one if it comes to that.

Comment: Well it seems what we did worked, I did have to set a cronjob for my first script but the second one finally worked by adding a sleep at the beginning and at the end of the .rb script.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are on a Unix/Linux system, you can run it in a `screen` session.  (This is a Unix command, not a scripting function.)

If you don't know what `screen` is, it's basically a "detachable" terminal session.  You can open a `screen` session, run this script, and then detach from that `screen` session.  That detached session will stay alive even after you log off, leaving your script running.  (You can re-attach to that `screen` session later if you want to shut it down manually.)

`screen` is pretty neat, and every developer on Unix/Linux should be aware of it.

**How to do this without reading any docs:**

- open a terminal session on the server that will run the script
- run `screen` - you will now be in a new shell prompt in a new screen session
- run your script
- type `ctrl-a` then `d` (without ctrl; the "d" is for "detach") to detach from the `screen` (but still leave it running)

Now you're back in your first shell.  Your script is still alive in your `screen` session.  You can disconnect and the `screen` session will keep on trucking.

Do you want to get back into that `screen` and shut the app down manually?  Easy!  Run `screen -r` (for "reattach").  To kill the `screen` session, just reattach and exit the shell.

You can have multiple `screen` sessions running concurrently, too.  (If there is more than one `screen` running, you'll need to provide an argument to `screen -r`.)

**Check out some `screen` docs!**

[Here's a screen howto.](http://www.phacks.net/how-to-use-gnu-screen/)  Search "gnu screen howto" for many more.

Comment: See also _tmux_, another screen multiplexor with a similar feature set.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS headless. I do not have tons of scripting knowledge I am learning this as I go.  Could you explain how to add the screen command to the script?

Comment: I added a simple howto.  You don't need to alter your script; just run it as-is inside the `screen`.

Comment: Great tutorial that will be nice for the future maybe, my only problem is my server shuts down ever night at 3 a.m. and starts back up at 10 a.m., my issue is not having up a putty terminal but automating it when i'm not around to start it up.

Comment: Well, I answered the question that you asked.  This shut-down-at-3am thing is new information.

Answer (score 1):

Use an infinite loop. Try:

```
while running do
  sleep(3600)
end
```

You can use exit to terminate when you need to. This will run the loop once an hour so it doesnt eat up processing time. An infinite loop before your disconnect method will prevent it from being called until the server shuts down.

Comment: I tried placing your loop at the beginning and end of the script and while sleep(3600) works while I have putty running with a terminal up as soon as I close the terminal and try and run it automatically the same happens it runs the script and then its like it is ending.

Comment: I think you might have to daemonize your process for it to not die.

Comment: Running it with rubyw wont open a new console. It should stay alive the whole time.